# How to create an Observable that only fires when it has subscribers, and provides the latest value to new subscribers immediately

Tags: javascript, rxjs, frp, reactive-extensions-js

I'm trying to create a stream/observable that...

1. Only outputs events when it has subscribers
2. Provides any new subscribers with the latest value.

The concrete case is that I need an observable that makes an Async API call whenever a particular event happens, but only if it has subscribers. I'm trying to avoid unnecessary API calls.

I've managed to create a stream that only fires when it has subscribers like this...

```
let dataStream = Rx.Observable
   .interval(1000) // Fire an event every second
   .singleInstance() // Only do something when we have subscribers
   .startWith(null) // kick start as soon as something subscribes
   .flatMapLatest(interval => SomeAPI.someDataGet()) // get data, returns a promise
```

And this works. If I `console.log(...)` in the `SomeAPI.someDataGet` method, I only see it firing when the stream has subscribers. And my implementation looks really nice because I do this to subscribe and unsubscribe which fits in very nicely with React component lifecycle methods.

```
let sub1;
sub1 = dataStream.subscribe(x => console.log('sub1', x));
sub1.dispose();
```

I also want any new subscribers to receive the latest value the instant they subscribe. This is where I'm struggling. If I do this...

```
let sub1, sub2;
sub1 = dataStream.subscribe(x => console.log('sub1', x));

setTimeout( () => {
    sub2 = dataStream.subscribe(x => console.log('sub2', x));
}, 1500)
```

...I don't see the `console.log` for `sub2` until the next interval.

If my understanding is correct. I need a [Hot Observable](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md#cold-vs-hot-observables). So I have tried to create a stream like this...

```
let dataStream = Rx.Observable
   .interval(1000) // Fire an event every second
   .singleInstance() // Only do something when we have subscribers
   .startWith(null) // kick start as soon as something subscribes
   .flatMapLatest(interval => SomeAPI.someDataGet()) // get data
   .publish() // Make this a hot observable;
```

Which as I understand it, should make `dataStream` a `hot observable`.

However, in my tests the second subscription still doesn't receive data until the next interval. In addition, this would introduce the requirement to connect and disconnect the dataStream when subscribing which is something I would like to avoid if possible.

I'm brand new to RxJS and I would not be surprised if I've misunderstood what's happening here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `.publish()`, use `.shareReplay(1)`.

Comment: Easy when you know how. Thanks.